# How to install Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, installation

How the hell to install tkinter on to my PC ?
I tried for week to install it. I can not figure it out. Please, Help.
How does it work ? Is there a site you install it from or what ?

Comment: it's already installed when you install Python...

Comment: Tkinter is installed with Python. Tkinter needs Tcl/Tk which is installed with Python too.

Comment: In some Linux distributions Tkinter comes in a separate package, and have to explicitly installed. Given the wording of the question, I guess the O.P. is on Windows though, where it is already installed. Otherwise, just search for "tkinter" in your linux  package manager - the exact name may vary (e.g. "python-tkinter", or just "tkinter" in others)

Answer (score 6):

Should be there already man...

```
from Tkinter import *
```

Comment: It version for Python 2. Add version for Python 3 with `tkinter`

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using Windows.  If so...

**Step 1.** Ignore the people who say to `import tkinter as tk` or "It should already be there".

You're not the only person to have this problem despite apparently *every* post on the Internet telling you one of those two (utterly unproductive) statements.  **deep breath**

**Step 2.** Understand what you're trying to do.

You're trying to do two things.  The first is to install the [Tk GUI toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk_(software)), also known as `Tcl/Tk`.  This is a collection of software that exists independently of Python which allows for GUI development.  The second is to have Python interact with `Tcl/Tk`.  This is done with the [`tkinter` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tkinter.html) which allows you to call `Tcl/Tk` using Python.

The Python installer, by default, installs `Tcl/Tk` along with `tkinter`.  The `tkinter` module is [part of the standard library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/560fa4db17983ce37c1453c057901c627b2c3abc/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L1).  Because `tkinter` is not useful without `Tcl/Tk` also installed, someone, somewhere, at some time, decided it wasn't worth packaging `tkinter` separately.  I don't know why.

Maybe you didn't install `Tcl/Tk` and `tkinter` when Python installed.  Maybe you decided to use a different GUI framework.  Maybe you thought "Why should I install something that I'll never use, along with an IDE I'll never use."  Maybe you later found out that a third-party library like `seaborn` requires it... **deep breath**

**Step 3.** Figure out how you want to accomplish the two things you're trying to do.

You have two options:

*Option 1.* Install [`Tcl/Tk` manually](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html#installwin).  Then maybe you can [find some saint who has packaged `tkinter` for you](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).  But maybe the versioning isn't correct.  So you could compile it from source and/or learn a lot about how Python packaging works.

*Option 2.* Rerun the Python installer.  Select "Modify".  Make sure that the "`tcl/tk and IDLE`" checkbox is ticked and press "Next" a bunch.

[image: Fix Python so that it has <code>tkinter</code>]

If all else fails, burn everything down and start from scratch.  But hopefully the second option works for you like it did for me.  :)

Answer (score 2):

For `Linux` with `aptitude`:

If you're using `Python 3` then you must install as follows (writing in a terminal):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Tkinter for `Python 2` (`python-tk`) is different from `Python 3`'s (`python3-tk`).

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to

`from tkinter import *`

In python3, the issue is with capitalization, so you should use `tkinter` instead of `Tkinter`.