# How do I fix Auto-py-to-exe; Error tkinter not found?

Tags: python

Whenever I run auto-py-to-exe in terminal, an error shows up

```
PS C:\Users\Usr\PycharmProjects\Hackathon> auto-py-to-exe
Error: tkinter not found
For linux, you can install tkinter by executing: "sudo apt-get install python3-tk"
```

How do I fix this?

I tried going to terminal and typing

```
pip install tk
```

but that didn't work.
Someone please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499602/how-to-install-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was just a capitalization issue in the auto-py-to-exe files. I went to dialogs.py, and the import statement should look like

```
from Tkinter import tk
```

But I edited that to lowercase the T

```
from tkinter import tk
```